# Create a /new view with form_for with non-blank fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a periodic_review resource. What I need is that when the user goes to the new periodic_review form the form fields are filled with the last periodic_review fields except for a date field. (imagine that the fields won't change so much from one daily_review to another). I have this on the controller:

```
  def new
    @periodic_review = PeriodicReview.where(user_id: @user_id).order("revision DESC").first
    @periodic_review.date = nil
  end
```

And this on the view:

```
<%= form_for(@periodic_review) do |f| %> ...
```

Now the problem is that because the form_for gets a non-empty @periodic_review, it generates an update form and not a creation form, thus sending the user to the update on submit. I've tried:

```
@periodic_review.id = nil
```

below the date = nil, but it crashes.

How does the form know if it's an update or a creation if it's not using the id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# rails < 3.1
new_record = old_record.clone

#rails >= 3.1
new_record = old_record.dup
```

I your code, for rails >= 3.1,

```
@periodic_review = PeriodicReview.where(user_id: @user_id).order("revision DESC").first.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

My way to do this :

```
last_periodic_review = PeriodicReview.where(user_id: @user_id).order("revision DESC").first
options = last_periodic_review.attributes.merge({ date: nil })
@periodic_review = PeriodicReview.build(options)
```

I think it's clearer than to clone an object.